# How to restore runOn Scheduler used in previous operator?

Tags: project-reactor

Folks, is it possible to obtain currently used `Scheduler` within an operator?

The problem that I have is that `Mono.fromFuture()` is being executed on a native thread (AWS CRT Http Client in my case). As result all subsequent operators are also executed on that thread. And later code wants to obtain class loader context that is obviously null. I realize that I can call `.publishOn(originalScheduler)` after `.fromFuture()` but I don't know what scheduler is used to materialize Mono returned by my function.

Is there elegant way to deal with this?

```kotlin
fun myFunction(): Mono<String> {
    return Mono.just("example")
        .flatMap { value ->
            Mono.fromFuture {
                // invocation of 3rd party library that executes Future on the thread created in native code.
            }
        }
        .map {
            val resource = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResources("META-INF/services/blah_blah");
            // NullPointerException because Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader() returns NULL
            resource.asSequence().first().toString()
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, because there's no guarantee that there is a `Scheduler` at all.

The place where the subscription is made and the data starts flowing could simply be a `Thread`. There is no mechanism in Java that allows an external actor to submit a task to an arbitrary thread (you have to provide the `Runnable` at `Thread` construction).

So no, there's no way of "returning to the previous `Scheduler`".

Usually, this shouldn't be an issue at all. If your your code is reactive it should also be non-blocking and thus able to "share" whichever thread it currently runs on with other computations.

If your code is blocking, it should off-load the work to a blocking-compatible `Scheduler` anyway, which you should explicitly chose. Typically: `publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())`. This is also true for CPU-intensive tasks btw.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, Simon. In my case the code is not blocking, but the relies on presence of class loader which is missing because it's native thread. How would you recommend to address this issue within Project Reactor paradigm?

Comment: if you need a java thread and the processing isn't blocking, then you can probably use `publishOn(Schedulers.parallel())` for instance, right?

Comment: I noticed interesting problem. Even if I add `.publishOn(Schedulers.parallel())` to each Mono that uses AWS SDK (which is hacky) it still doesn't help because Reactor's scheduler creates thread lazily, from native aws' thread, thus inheriting its null class loader. How would you recommend to fix it?